# Meteor.js google account : filter email and force account choser

Tags: meteor, google-account

In my Meteor.js application, I'm using the accounts-google package in order to be connected with a google account. I have two questions about it.

First, is there a simple way to filter the account used? I would like that the users can connect only with google accounts belonging to my company. Our google account mails end with @mycompany.com. So it would be a simple mail filtering.
I already done that with some post log in hooks but I was wondering if there was a simpler way for doing it.

My second question is how to force the opening of the google account choser. For now, if I try to connect with a wrong google account, and if I only added this account (like in gmail, drive, etc), the google choser doesn't pop and automatically connect with this wrong account. So, in this case, the user is totally blocked (my application disconnect him if he tries to log in with a wrong account but the google account module doesn't propose him to connect with another account).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: To answer your first question check out the `Accounts.config`. You can restrict creation by email domain (`restrictCreationByEmailDomain`) http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_config.

Comment: Did you consider creating a local fork of the `google` package?

Answer (score 2):

In order to restrict signup/login to your domain, simply do on the server:

```
var checkEmailAgainstAllowed = function(email) {
  var allowedDomains = ['mycompanydomain.com'];
  var allowedEmails = ['otheruser@fromotherdomain.com','anotheruser@fromanotherdomain.com'];
  var domain = email.replace(/.*@/,'').toLowerCase();
  email = email.toLowerCase();
  return _.contains(allowedEmails, email) || _.contains(allowedDomains, domain);
};

Accounts.config({
  restrictCreationByEmailDomain: function(email) {
    if (!email) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(403,'This email address is not allowed');
    }
    if (!checkEmailAgainstAllowed(email)) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(403,'This email domain is not allowed');
    }
    return true;
  }
});
```

And to login, you'll need on the client:

```
Meteor.loginWithGoogle({
  forceApprovalPrompt: true, //this is what you want, to rerequest approval each time that prompts the google login prompt
  loginStyle         : "redirect", //or not, depending on your need
  requestPermissions : ['profile', 'email'],
  requestOfflineToken: true
}, function (err) {
  if (err)
  // set a session variable to display later if there is a login error  
  Session.set('loginError', 'reason: ' + err.reason + ' message: ' + err.message || 'Unknown error');
});
```

*Side note:
Alternatively, you can set up your routes so that every time a new route is called, you login, and every time a route is destroyed or on windows's unload, you call logout. This causes login/logout roundtrip everytime the route changes, but you'll make sure that the new user always has a fresh session*

Edit:
When you log out of your meteor app, you don't log out of google. That's how oauth works. So, basically, if you want a meteor log out to also log the user out of their google account, so that the next time they come back, they need to provide credentials again, you should do:

```
Meteor.logout(function(e) {
  if (e) {
    console.log("Could not log the user out")
  } else {
    window.location.replace('https://accounts.google.com/Logout');
  }
});
```

This uses the callback of `Meteor.logout()` so that when the logout is successfull, the user is redirected to google's central account logout url where the user is also logged out of all google services.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Filtering the mail addresses with Accounts.config works perfectly. Yet, the "forceApprovalPrompt" doesn't force the account choser popup. I'm still blocked with my single none authorized account, and can't chose another one.
To be sur, where do I have to put the call to Meteor.loginWithGoogle function?

Comment: Okay, I was not using the function correctly. So now I create a basic button, and in the corresponding template event, I call Meteor.loginWithGoogle. I can now confirm that the 'forceApprovalPrompt' option (thus the name is kinda meaningful^^) forces the approval page, not the account choser page. So if I only remembered one account, I will be still forced logged in with this account.

Comment: In that case, your only option would be to log the user out on window's unload event and call loginwithgoogle automatically on load (instead of requiring user click). this will make sure login prompt (account chooser) comes in. But it is a hack, and I don't recommend it for public apps, it may only be good for internal business apps where the users know that this is how it works. Check this for reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/ggZwNTPNqQI

Comment: I think I was not clear about the problem. The problem comes from the google part. Let say i'm disconnected from the app, and from any google account. I go to the app, hit the connect button, i'm redirectee to the google account page. This page ask me my credentials (as i was totally disconnected from a'y account). Let's say I use my legit company account. The google account page redirect me back to the app, the app redirect me to the home page. Now, I disconnect from the app (Meteor.logout()), the app redirect me on the login page.

Comment: Now, if I hit the login button, I'm still redirected to the google account page, but this page doesn't ask me what account to use, and take the precedent account (this account was remembered on the google side). So I can't chose another account. The problem is totally on the google side, so if there is no magical option to force the account choser, I don't know what can I do :/

Comment: I updated the answer with what I now think you are looking for.